# Phrase to describe a chair being pulled

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, sounds

I'm lost for words to complete this sentence:

> The sound of the chair ***_*** against the floor can be heard clearly as the room silence with my sudden action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you’re looking for is probably [scrape](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scrape?q=scrape) (sense 2.1 and 2.2.):

> The sound of the chair **scraping** against the floor could be heard clearly as the room suddenly went silent at my sudden action.

(Note that “as the room silence with my sudden action” does not make any sense. ‘Sudden action’ in itself sounds quite odd in this context, but I don’t know what exactly your ‘sudden action’ was, so I’ve left that as is.)

Answer (score 1):

Scraping. "The sound of the chair scraping against the floor".
My interpretation of the second half your sentence leads me to belive that you mean "silenced", as in "fell silent".
"The sound of the chair scraping against the floor can be heard clearly as the room silenced with my sudden action."
Perhaps "fell silent" might be more appropriate in that sense?
"The sound of the chair scraping against the floor can be heard clearly as the room fell silent with my sudden action."

Answer (score 0):

the high-pitched screeching noise of chairs being shoved  around on the tiled floor

Comment: Would you mind editing yourself and adding some comment that answers the question a bit more fully?

Answer (score 0):

Scraping, dragging, sliding, moving or edging would work. Depends on the mood you're trying to convey.